# Выпадающее меню на html+css, нужна инспекция кода

Tags: html, css, инспекция-кода

Сделал выпадающее меню. Всё работает, меня только один вопрос интересует: всё ли корректно, может ли данный код считаться хорошим?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
}
.q1{
 margin-left:40px;
 margin-top:50px;
 border:1px black solid;
 text-align:center;
}
.q2{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 vertical-align:top;
 z-index:1000;
 overflow:hidden;
 height:42px;
 transition:all 1s;
 width:17%;
}
.q2 a{
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:12px 0px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 background:black;
}
.q3{
 position:absolute;
 top:-90px;
 right:0; 
 width:100%;
 transition:all 1s;
 z-index:-1;
}
.q3 li{
 display:block;
}
.q3 a{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:12px 0px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 background:red;
 margin-bottom:3px;
}
.q2:hover .q3{
 top:45px;
}
.q2:hover{
 height:177px;
}
.q3 li:last-child a{
 margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="q1">
 
<li class="q2">
<a href="#">123</a><ul class="q3"><li><a href="#">111</a></li><li><a href="#">222</a></li><li><a href="#">333</a></li></ul>
</li>

<li class="q2"><a href="#">123</a><ul class="q3"><li><a href="#">111</a></li><li><a href="#">222</a></li><li><a href="#">333</a></li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @PeGaS HTML (от англ. HyperText Markup Language — «язык гипертекстовой разметки»)

Comment: На мой взгляд именования классов крайне не информативные

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как называются знаки на html,css ?

Comment: @Bald Наименования согласен, но это только для примера